# Update Set value 1 if value else set 0

Tags: sql

I was just woking trough some old final exams as I stumbled across this task:

Table:

[image: Table]

Create a **single** SQL query from this table which will check if `Art_MWStSatz` is 7% and set `Art_Markierung` to 1 if it is, else set `Art_Markierung` to 0.

I dont't have any idea on how to solve this. I asked my teacher by she didn't know an answer either.

Some translations:

- Artikel = Item
- MWSt Satz = vat rate
- Markierung = mark

I don't have access to the solution so it all depends in your answers.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or MS Access? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Let me see if I got this: you want to check that if Art_MWStSatz is 7% then set Art_Markierung to 1 else to 0?

Comment: @cdrrrrr yes this it what I want

Comment: I'm curious how your teacher doesn't know the answer to this since she gave you this in order to solve it...

Comment: @cdrrrrr she just told us to do solve some final exams I am pretty sure she didn't even look at them.

Comment: @jarlh this is what was available to me.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there are no dbms defined in final exams. The just tell you to use SQL thats all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an UPDATE and a CASE. This assumes that '7%' is a string and not the int '7'

```
   UPDATE table
      SET
          Art_Markierung = CASE
                               WHEN Art_MWStSatz = '7%'
                               THEN 1
                               ELSE 0
                           END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume that 1 or 0 is `true` or `false`. In this situation, you can use a `CASE` like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Art_Markierung = CASE Art_MWStSatz
                     WHEN '7%' THEN CAST(1 AS bit) 
                     ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
                     END
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume `Art_Markierung` and `Art_MWStSatz` are integer:

```
UPDATE Artikel
    SET Art_Markierung = 
        CASE
            WHEN Art_MWStSatz = 7 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END
```